How to use DateTime data from Ajax in Tabulator?
New to Tabulator, however, I've managed to get a sample html/json script to communicate correctly with a PHP backend via Ajax/json callbacks.
I can see data come through, view and edit etc for numbers and strings, however, for some reason datetime values appear to be blank?
In the json that comes from the server, I've tried different text formats e.g.:

...."DateVal": "01/02/2025", ...
...."DateVal": "01-02-2025 10:30:00", ...
...."DateVal": "01-02-2025T10:30:00", ...

In the 'columns' setup within tabulator I have:
{title:"DateVal", field:"DateVal",sorter:"datetime", width:150, headerFilter:true, formatter:"datetime", editor:"datetime"},

I can confirm that I've included luxon:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>


In all cases, I get a blank field for the date - also, when I edit the field, and use the datetime picker, (I can see a date being constructed in the field), but when I come out of the field, the date field returns to blank...?
I suspect I've missed something (as mentioned, numbers and strings work fine)...
If someone could give me an idea where I've gone wrong...
Many thanks
Carl.
What I'd expect to see is the date that I've retrieved via JSON, or if I'm editing, when I come out of the date picker, I'd like to see the date remain in the field, so it can be passed back via ajax to update the database.
Also, when I use the date picker, it would be nice if the date picker would start with the date thats actually in the field, rather than going straight to 'today' - so if I accidentally click in the field, I don't have to remember what its original value was...

Hi
ok - realised that I'd not included 'formatterParams' - apparently thats mandatory - so thats working now...
Only thing that remains is how to I preserve the original date/time values when clicking into the field, or opening the date/datetime picker...?

Also, even though I'm using the formatter in tabulator, it comes up with 'invalid date' even though the date has just been selected through the picker...   (bit of a learning curve here) - I'm currently using 'invalidPlaceholder:true' to get around this...
